# Find error (line of error) in sql server managment studio message window

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have Over 5000 insert query that i want to execute in Sql server mangement studio(SSMS)
when these insert query execute with no problem in message window show **Query Executed Successfully**
but my problem is when some of them of these query has error the message is **query completed with error** and in message window its difficult to find between

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1...

****My Error Detail .... ****

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

is there any way just sql server show error in message window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way I Found It
Open quick find window from edit menu and search for "Msg"
I could found error by this way.

Answer (score 6):

To suppress the rows affected messages, use [`SET NOCOUNT ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can also start SQL Server Profiler to show only the errors as shown in the image below

[image]